# RecyclerView change layout for edit item and update data after eddit

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView with items. My Items look like this(1):

[image]

When I click on Item I need an item like 2 or 3.

if like 2 - I do I need update data in DB for each change -+ or add "apply" button

How can I make this logic? I do not want use libraries and make bu default android tools. But if it hard maby you advise libraries

Comment: you at least write why put a minus.

Answer (score -1):

You can manage multiple view type in recycleview. Check sample code for your reference.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    class ViewHolder0 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


   ...
    public ViewHolder0(View itemView){
    ...
    }
}

class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ...
    public ViewHolder2(View itemView){
    ...
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // Just as an example, return 0 or 2 depending on position
    // Note that unlike in ListView adapters, types don't have to be contiguous
    return position % 2 * 2;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     switch (viewType) {
         case 0: return new ViewHolder0(...);
         case 2: return new ViewHolder2(...);
         ...
     }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case 0:
            ViewHolder0 viewHolder0 = (ViewHolder0)holder;
            ...
            break;

        case 2:
            ViewHolder2 viewHolder2 = (ViewHolder2)holder;
            ...
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Give specific reason for downvoting